# What is the difference between declaring an enum with and without 'typedef'?

Tags: c++, enums, declaration, typedef

The standard way of declaring an enum in C++ seems to be:

```
enum <identifier> { <list_of_elements> };
```

However, I have already seen some declarations like:

```
typedef enum { <list_of_elements> } <identifier>;
```

What is the difference between them, if it exists? Which one is correct?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

C compatability.

In C, `union`, `struct` and `enum` types have to be used with the appropriate keyword before them:

```
enum x { ... };

enum x var;
```

In C++, this is not necessary:

```
enum x { ... };

x var;
```

So in C, lazy programmers often use `typedef` to avoid repeating themselves:

```
typedef enum x { ... } x;

x var;
```

Comment: Just want to note that I'm not using "lazy" pejoratively here.

Comment: indeed, it is one of that qualities that make a good programmer :)

Comment: Impatience and hubris being the others.

Comment: ROFL @Steve You nailed it! :D

Comment: @Soham: not me, Larry Wall :-)

Comment: So be it then, so be it.
Dont you think the hubris bit was a sarcasm.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the difference is that in standard C if you use

```
enum <identifier> { list }
```

You would have to call it using

```
enum <identifier> <var>;
```

Where as with the typedef around it you could call it using just

```
<identifier> <var>;
```

However, I don't think it would matter in C++

Answer (score 3):

Similar to what @Chris Lutz said:

In old-C syntax, if you simply declared:

> ```
> enum myEType {   ... };
> ```

Then you needed to declare variables as:

> ```
> enum myEType myVariable;
> ```

However, if you use typedef:

> ```
> typedef enum {   ... } myEType;
> ```

Then you could skip the enum-keyword when using the type:

> ```
> myEType myVariable;
> ```

C++ and related languages have done away with this restriction, but its still common to see code like this either in a pure C environment, or when written by a C programmer.